# Why would anyone "pull the stem out and stop the wristwatch at night or when not wearing it" in the context of mechanical watches?

Tags: mechanical-engineering, mechanisms, mechanical, watch

I read this the other day while discussing mechanical pocket and wrist watches:

> Plus it is common practice to pull the stem out and stop the wristwatch at night or when not wearing it. You then have to set everything each time you put it on. That's what the regulator clock on the mantle is for.

Why would anyone "stop the wristwatch at night"? Or ever? "Pull the stem out"? Why deliberately cause *more* problems for yourself? I can understand forgetting to wind it up for 33+ hours so that it has stopped naturally, but why *actively go out of your way* to manually stop it instead of just winding it up so that it's ready when you wake up and doesn't have to be set every day?

Don't tell me this is some sort of "wear and tear" thing? Surely they can't be *that* fragile, as to require a "good night's sleep" like a human?

Comment: There is wear and tear involved, even at the scale of mechanical watches. Springs take sets; gears, bearings and sprockets wear, all these lead to inaccurate measurements. Why run something for 24 hours when you only need 16? You effectively extend it's life 50%.

Comment: @jko Well... Because it's a massive PITA to set the time against some other clock every day as compared to just winding it up?

Comment: Yes you've reiterated your question and I suggested an answer a person that still wears mechanical watches could make.

Comment: This sounds just like you: https://engineering.stackexchange.com/q/44917/10902

Comment: you are asking a question about some unknown person's behavior ... how can such a question be answered without asking that specific person? ... what does it have to do with engineering?

Comment: @jko FWIW the only component that was worn out and failed (and done that *twice*) in the 60 years I have been using the same mechanical watch (24 hours a day, and zero maintenance) was --- ***the stem.*** And it's an automatic winding watch, so the stem was only ever used to correct the time occasionally. Who knows how many stems I would have got through if I "pulled it out" every night to stop the watch! (It's a good quality watch, but not in the top price range - the last time a professional put a value on it, his estimate was around £2,000.)

Comment: If this is "best practice." I wonder why most owners of expensive mechanical watches use automatic winders to keep them running continuously when not being worn.

Comment: Just spitballin ideas that seem to make sense for pulling out. Doesn't seem to make sense in general to have a watch at all anymore as most people have phones, some of which have turned into watches anyway. Never a fan of having anything expensive on my person.

Comment: This is the first time I've been made aware that some people might pull out a watch stem to stop it over night & then reset the time in the morning using a mantle clock. Firstly, not everyone has a mantle clock. Secondly, doing this is fine if someone has the time to do it every morning. It's easier to let the watch run over night & put on one's wrist in the morning, showing the correct time (assuming the watch keeps time accurately for extended periods).

Comment: It would be nice if you could credit the source of the excerpt you posted. Indeed it seems a very uncommon practice to me,  I've actually never heard of somebody doing so.

Comment: The comment was mine. I'm a mechanic most of the time and don't wear any watches or rings or anything. I wear the watch maybe once a month or so. But my dad always did that when I was a kid. That's where I got it from.

Comment: @PhilSweet thank you, interesting, many different habits make world an interesting place to live. My dad use to teach me to take off and charge my watch every night before going to sleep. Time alignment was then due at every opportunity, a time signal on the radio or TV or something alike

Answer (score -1):

Mechanical watches wear out.  They have to be rebuilt every 5 years or so.  This method prevents wear, and also lets you spread the life amongst several watches daily, versus the wear of multiple watches winding down and the same time.

Comment: By pulling out, you will need to re-wind, readjust time, then push to restart, create more mechanical tears and wear. I guess many of you haven't ever seen a mechanical watch, not to mention owned one.

Comment: @r13 you don't have to be a punk about it.  Is this how you talk to people in person? Build your own site since you consider yourself to be the sole arbiter of answers.  Your seagull activity here isn't needed.

Comment: Yes, this is the way I talk to passing the fact. Sorry to offend you unintentionally.

Comment: BTW, your "5 years" remark may be correct in an "overall" sense, but the Swiss watch makes may feel offended, as they pride their product on its accuracy and longevity that has been constantly reflected in the price tag to date.

Comment: BTW, you shouldn't guess when trying to assess "facts"

Comment: My mechanical watch needs less attention that a battery watch which needs the battery replacing every 2 years... Which is why I no longer buy battery driven watches...

Comment: 5 years lifetime seems a huge underestimate, I've had several mechanical watches in my life, I've never seen anything broken but wristbands.

Comment: @carloc Rolex recommends 10 year service intervals, cheaper watches will require service more often.